# Varias tablas en un mismo reporte de Jasper Report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

he buscado varios documentos en internet para documentarme sobre el problema y nada...

La pregunta es la siguiente, como puedo generar varias tablas en un mismo reporte con jasper report, porque lo he realizado con una sola tabla por informe, pero si quiero que en un reporte se vean varias tablas no me muestra nada.

Podrían ayudarme? muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre resolverlo, para generar varias tablas en un mismo reporte funciono para mi el crear varios detalles dejando uno de por medio para generar las tablas en el cuerpo del reporte.

Espero les sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola puedes dar mas detalles sobre como lo resolviste? estoy en la misma situación.